# Quote and intent

Tags: android-intent, quote

Output of the below code needs to look like this:

```
The following is a quote:
"now is the time
for all "good" men
to come to the
aid of their party"
```

```java
public class Quote { 
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        System.out.println("The following is a quote:\n\"now is the time\nfor all\"good\"men\ntocome to the\naid of their party\"");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

`System.out.println("The following is a quote:\n"+"now is the time\nfor all \"good\" men \nto come to the\naid of their party");`

Output:

```
The following is a quote:
now is the time
for all "good" men
to come to the
aid of their party
```

`System.out.println("The following is a quote:\nnow is the time for all \"good\" men to come to the aid of their party");`

Output -

```
The following is a quote:
now is the time for all "good" men to come to the aid of their party
```

In java, You can escape quote using `\`

Example - `System.out.println("This is \"10\"");`

So to print a `"` use a `\` like `\"`

Comment: I have to include "The following is a quote: (I try to indent this) > "now is the time on the second  line

Comment: @new does the answer help you get desired result now?